# How to sync extension and theme in google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When i logged in to google chrome after installing. The extensions and theme doesnot sync. Bookmarks are synced. How to make google-chrome sync both of them.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is known: [Issue 170107](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170107)

The solution is to go to ***Extensions***, enable ***Developer mode*** and press ***Update extensions now***. That will immediately pull all the extensions for your account.

Comment: WOW i didn't see that one coming! You solution works wonderfully. Thanks a lot friend. Everything synced in a matter of minuites. Thanks again.