# Chromium does not sync bookmarks or extensions

Tags: 12.04, chromium, sync

I've installed a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 but i can't seem to sync my bookmarks or extensions when i log-in chromium. Then i tried installing chrome and same thing happened.

I have searched it on google but can't find any useful info.

Question:  How can I make it Sync properly?

Comment: This helped me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/245069/how-to-sync-extension-and-theme-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to Chromium. That should sync the bookmarks. Then sign out of Chromium, sign in again, and do CTRL+SHIFT+DEL. Clear data from the beginning of time, and check everything except for the last two options.

Comment: sorry.still not syncing

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Del clears the cache.  It has nothing to do with the Sync capability.